# How I can make a course app?

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to make a application  with this [style](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quizmine.cppandroid&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5xdWl6bWluZS5jcHBhbmRyb2lkIl0.)

that's a course app about some subject. I want to know how I can store the course pages, with all formatting (Is there possible use a `HTML` page to maintaing the order?) and where to save theses pages, with images and maybe videos?

Anyone knows for where I can begin?
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use HTML to create your pages, and then make your app being just single WebView object showing your pages. You put your HTML pages and related resources in `res/assets` folder

Answer (score 0):

You can store course pages as xml, json, html and save this information on SD card or in resources of your app. If you plan a lot of images an videos it's better to use SD card and download data from network.